# How to filter an objects where is employeeId equals to some value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockoutjs, but the question is really in Javascript domain.

I have variable `vm.filteredSerivces()` which contains all services by all employees.
Now, I want to just preserve those filteredSerivces where is `vm.filteredSerivces()[0].GroupedServices[x].EmployeeId == 3684` (x is the number of index number of each object in GroupedServices object list)

I tried as follows:

```
var filteredSrvcs = vm.filteredSerivces()[0].GroupedServices.filter(x => x.EmployeeId != Id).remove();
vm.filteredSerivces(filteredSrvcs );
```

But I changed structure in that way, and my bindings in html is not corresponding.

Is there any other way to just remove this sub-sub object, and to preserve a structure as it is?

Here is the [image]

Comment: That image is totally useless to us. Provide some sample data and expected results if you want help as per [mre]

Comment: my objects `vm.filteredSerivces()` has sub-object `GroupedServices`, and I want to remove some objects from that sub-object called GroupedServices, as you can see on the photo, GroupedServices has 2 objects (with id's : 5247 and 5254). I want to remove all objects from that GroupedSerivces object that Id != from some number

Comment: without sample data how are we supposed to run the code you tried and see what it produces or where it is going wrong. We have no idea what gets returned from `vm.filteredSerivces()`

Comment: Yes, I know @charlietfl Here it is, you can see from js window the structure, for some reason it doesnt work on click from a demo https://jsfiddle.net/jp9davhc/

Comment: So you probably want to loop over the outer array and filter each one

Comment: yes. I want to remove all sub-objects for each main item where `id != some value`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that maps a new array of new objects and the filter is set to only include the GroupedServices items where Id == 2000

```js
let res = data.map(({ServiceTypeName, GroupedServices}) =>{
   GroupedServices= GroupedServices.filter(({Id}) => Id == 2000);
   return {ServiceTypeName,GroupedServices }
})

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
  let data = 
  [
  {
    "ServiceTypeName": "Type 1",
    "GroupedServices": [{
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "A"
    }, {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "A"
    },
    {
      "Id": 28456,
      "Name": "AGSADGJS"
    }]
 },
 {
 "ServiceTypeName": "Type 2",
    "GroupedServices": [{
      "Id": 1203,
      "Name": "AHASJ"
    }, {
      "Id": 2000,
      "Name": "AHSJD"
    },
    {
      "Id": 284536,
      "Name": "UEHNCK"
    }]
 }];
 </script>
```

Comment: Yes! that's it! I will accept your answer, just I need on the same example, additional clause - `GroupedServices.length > 0` so basically, I want to remove also an object `ServiceTypeName` if it's object GroupedServices no any children. Thanks